# Multiple websites in IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, website

I have a VPS with a single IP address running IIS 7.0

Am I right in saying to host multiple websites on different domains I would:

- Set the domain name's primary nameserver to point to my VPS IP.
- Set the binding for the particular website to the chosen domain.

Bingo, each website would now go to the right place in IIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - you point the domain's NS records to wherever you have DNS hosting for that domain. Then in your DNS hosting, you create A records for example.com and probably www.example.com that point to the IP of your server.